# (Linux-Bash) Create an account for each user and add the user to its group from a text file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a username.txt which contains their username and specific group. As of right now i'm trying to create a bash script which allows me to create an account for each user and add the user to its group in one command.

this is currently my failed bash script(i know pretty much everything is wrong but i hope you guys got a clear idea on it):

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo addgroup staff
sudo addgroup visitors

username="username.txt"

while read line; do
sudo useradd $-Eo '^[^,]+' $username;
if [grep staff $username]; then
  sudo usermod -a -G staff
else
  sudo usermod -a -G visitors
done < $username
```

This is what is inside my username.txt file:

```
ellipsiscoterie,visitor
magnetcommonest,visitor
belateddefensive,staff
bobstercaramelize,staff
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366569/linux-bash-read-each-word-seperated-by-comma ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "needs more focus" because there is a large number of bugs in your code, many of which would be trivially reported by a simple check like http://shellcheck.net/ -- in the future, please review the guidance for providing a [mre] of one specific, repeatable problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo addgroup staff
sudo addgroup visitors

username="username.txt"
```

OK. There is some debate about using `sudo` in scripts, but I'm not against it.

```
while read line; do
```

You read the line from STDIN, which is your input file. The variable `line` contains `ellipsiscoterie,visitor` in the first iteration.

```
sudo useradd $-Eo '^[^,]+' $username;
```

`$-` prints The current set of options in your current shell. It will produce something like `himBH`. The next argument seems a regular expression, and the last argument is the filename that you use. So the command here is:

```
sudo useradd himBHEo '^[^,]+' username.txt
```

Hint: if you are unsure of the arguments, check with an echo  (`echo $-Eo '^[^,]+' $username`) before you add them to a sudo-ed command.

This is not what you want. First, you probably want to use the variable `line` instead of `username`. Why would you otherwise loop through that file?

Second, read-up on variable expansion in `bash`. For now, try:

```
line=ellipsiscoterie,visitor
echo ${line%,*}
echo ${line#*,}
```

So the line would probably need to be:

```
sudo useradd ${line%,*}
```

```
if [grep staff $username]; then
```

This is wrong in almost everything.

- the `[` and `]` require spaces to set them apart
- but you dont want to do a `test`, you want to see if the grep succeeds, so the `[` and `]` are not needed anyway
- you are again using the complete file. So the `grep` succeeds if there is any line with `staff` in it; even if the username would be `johnfalstaff`

What you really want to know is if the second column in your `line` is `staff`, so:

```
if [ "${line#*,}" = "staff" ] ; then
```

```
  sudo usermod -a -G staff
else
  sudo usermod -a -G visitors
```

So, where is the `fi` that closes the `if` statement?

```
done < $username
```

Also, [quote the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable): `done < "$username"`

Comment: Also, use `read -r` to avoid trouble with the legacy behavior of `read`.

Comment: Yeah, I may have missed some more points too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to write it in one line. In this case, `awk` splits each row into different columns and you can access each field separately.

```
awk -F "," '{ if(system("grep -q -E "$2" /etc/group") != 0 ){system("groupadd "$2)}; system("useradd "$1" -G "$2)}' username.txt
```

The first argument (-F ",") defines the field-separator, but it could be also something else e.g. ";" or "/"

The part `if(system("grep -q -E "$2" /etc/group") != 0 )` verifies if the group exist and if not, the part `{system("groupadd "$2)}` creates the group before the next command `system("useradd "$1" -G "$2)` creates the user and adds it to the group $2.

It's possible to simplify the command to remove the if part, but then you will get a warning message that the user already exists.

```
awk -F "," '{ system("groupadd "$2); system("useradd "$1" -G "$2)}' username.txt
groupadd: group 'visitor' already exists
groupadd: group 'staff' already exists
```

btw: the part `system` executes just an operating system command

Answer (score 0):

The newusers command allows you to configure users from a file in batch:

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/newusers.8.html