# Read each word separated by comma

Tags: bash, unix

As of right now, I'm trying to reach each word, with the first word being `useradd` and the second word being `groupadd`, but I'm having a bit of trouble with the ","

This is my `username.txt` file:

```
jason,staff
henson,visitor
```

This is my current bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

username="username2.txt"

while read username group; do
  sudo useradd $username;
  sudo groupadd $group;
done < $username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the field separator `IFS` to comma.

```
filename="username2.txt"
while IFS=, read -r username group
do
    sudo useradd "$username"
    sudo groupadd "$group"
done < "$filename"
```

And don't reuse the variable `$username` for both the file and your iteration variable.

Comment: btw erm, any idea how i can make their initial password the same as their username?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script